# why is run_callbacks necessary on the method with the same name as the callback when ActiveSupport::Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, activesupport

I've made this test class to experiment with callbacks not in AR. But for some reason I have to manually call them. Which just seems pointless, in a way.

```
  class TestClass
    include ActiveSupport::Callbacks

    define_callbacks :save

    set_callback :save, :before, :speak
    set_callback :save, :after, :bark

    def save
      puts 'saving...'
    end
    def other_it 
      run_callbacks :save do
        puts 'saving...'
      end
    end
    def speak
      puts "hi"
    end
    def bark
      puts "ruff"
    end

  end
```

It seems like I wouldn't have to specify the run_callback method in the :save method, but I apparently have to. What am I missing? See this output:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :016 > t = TestClass.new
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :017 > t.save
saving...
 => nil 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :018 > t.other_it
hi
saving...
ruff
 => nil
```

The save callbacks are not run in the save method, unless I call them manually.